# Google Maps hide/show markers undefined not a function

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [ 
        <?php $i = 0; if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); $location = get_field('adres'); ?>

        ['<?php echo $location['address']; ?>', <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>,<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>, <?php echo $i; ?>],

        <?php $i++; endwhile; endif; ?>
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [       
        <?php if($loop->have_posts()) : while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); $location = get_field('adres'); ?>
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3><?php echo $location['address']; ?></h3>' +
        '<p>Rodzaj: <?php the_field('rodzaj_wagi');?><br />' +
        'Numer: <?php the_field('numer');?><br />' +
        'Ilość: <?php the_field('ilość');?><br />' +
        'Data: <?php the_field('data');?></p>' +
        '</div>'],
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    ];

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                setVisible(false);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(6);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    $('#testCheckbox').click(function(){    
        markers[0].setVisible(false);
    });

}
```

That should display markers from database (WordPress) - that's work fine. But I have to add hide/show checkbox. I tried test with **markers[0].setVisible(false);** - last lines of script.. But I always get **undefined is not a function** error. Any ideas?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markers array is not an array of google.maps.Markers, they won't have a .setVisible method (or a setMap method). Keep your google.maps.Markers in an array of google.maps.Markers, use that array to hide/show the markers.

In the global scope:

```
var gmarkers = [];
```

when you create the marker push it onto this new array:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map,
  title: markers[i][0]
});
gmarkers.push(marker);
```

Then this will work (note the change from `markers` to `gmarkers`):

```
$('#testCheckbox').click(function(){    
    gmarkers[0].setVisible(false);
});
```

Comment: Thank You. I tried push markers into array, but wrong way, so I thought that it can't work. Thanks for help :)